# Insert rows on table from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table on my database, where I have this columns: [id, userId, locationId, created, update], and what I want to do is insert all users from a location to other location, except the users that exists on the second location (and if this new entries could have the date of this new insert on the columns created and updated, would be fantastic). I mean, if I had this table:

```
id | userId | location | created | updated
 1 |      1 |        1 | 1234567 | 1234567
 2 |      2 |        1 | 9876543 | 9876543
 3 |      1 |        2 | 5555555 | 6666666
```

Assuming that the actual time is 9999999, after the insert operation, the result must to be this:

```
id | userId | location | created | updated
 1 |      1 |        1 | 1234567 | 1234567
 2 |      2 |        1 | 9876543 | 9876543
 3 |      1 |        2 | 5555555 | 6666666
 4 |      2 |        2 | 9999999 | 9999999
```

Any solution?? Thanks.

**EDIT (considering more cases)**

There is some more information that I hadn´t considered. On the example, there is a transfer of data in only one direction: the info goes from location 1 to location 2. Mostly, because there was no user on the location 2 that location 1 didn´t have.
The perfect solution would be that the transfer went in two directions, or even using more than 2 locations, something like this:

```
id | userId | location | created | updated
 1 |      1 |        1 | 1234567 | 1234567
 2 |      2 |        1 | 9876543 | 9876543
 3 |      1 |        2 | 5555555 | 6666666
 4 |      3 |        2 | 1829384 | 0192837
 5 |      4 |        3 | 8888833 | 9991828
 6 |      5 |        4 | 1111111 | 2222222
```

Assuming that the actual time is 9999999, AND I want to involve only the locations 1, 2 and 3, after the insert operation, the result must to be this:

```
id | userId | location | created | updated
 1 |      1 |        1 | 1234567 | 1234567
 2 |      2 |        1 | 9876543 | 9876543
 3 |      1 |        2 | 5555555 | 6666666
 4 |      3 |        2 | 1829384 | 0192837
 5 |      4 |        3 | 8888833 | 9991828
 6 |      5 |        4 | 1111111 | 2222222
              /*news*/
 7 |      3 |        1 | 9999999 | 9999999
 8 |      4 |        1 | 9999999 | 9999999
 9 |      2 |        2 | 9999999 | 9999999
10 |      4 |        2 | 9999999 | 9999999
11 |      1 |        3 | 9999999 | 9999999
12 |      2 |        3 | 9999999 | 9999999
13 |      3 |        3 | 9999999 | 9999999
```

The location 1, 2 and 3 share their users, but not the location 4.
This could be the best solutions, BUT I would settle for that the locations share their data with the others one by one... and programmatically I can make a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do I to create a multi column unique index on userid - location fields. This would prevent duplicate user ids for the same location to be inserted.

Then use an `insert ignore ... select ...` query to insert the users from the other location. Ignore means that MySQL will ignore duplicate key violation errors and will carry on inserting the valid users:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO yourtable (userId, location, created, update)
SELECT userId, new_location, now(), now()
FROM youtable as t2
WHERE t2.location=current_location
```

new_location and current_location are parameters that you need to provide in the query.

Comment: Thanks @Shadow, I am a little afraid because this is a legacy project, and until now this table didn´t use this unique index... I think I have covered all possibilities programmatically (with php), but I am going to ask a little more about the Giorgios answer in first instance, and if I am not able to understand, I am going to make local tests before upload. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to keep userid - location pairs unique, then the easiest way is to declare a unique index on these 2 fields. Otherwise, you need to ensure in each and every part of the code that you check the uniqueness of the data before updating the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like the following:

```
INSERT INTO mytable  (`userId`, `location`, `created`, `updated`)
SELECT userId, IF(location = 1, 2, 1), NOW(), NOW()
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY userId 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT location) = 1;
```

The query assumes that `id` field is auto-increment and can thus be excluded from the `INSERT` operation. It also assumes that there are only two available `location` values, namely `1` and `2`.

Comment: I believe you need to alias mytable in the select part, otherwise it is not going to work.

Comment: Hello @Giorgios, I am not sure  about  if I understand somethings on your answer, fo example: what is the meaning of 1, 2, 1 in "IF(location = 1, 2, 1)"?? What happens if there are more available location, but I only want to merge only two? and if I would merge more than two locations? and last question What is the direction of the merge?? I make an edit to provide more info, If you could beat him out, please. Thanks.

Comment: If you have more than 2 locations, then Giorgos' solution will not work because it is going to merge all other locations to the one in the condition of the if. As described his answer, he assumed that you only had 2 locations. The if() function is described in the MySQL documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Use `INSERT ....SELECT Statement`

For created and update date you can use `MySQL UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function

Like this

```
INSERT INTO LOCATION2 (id, userId, locationId, created, update)
SELECT id, userId, locationId, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), UNIX_TIMESTAMP() FROM LOCATION1
```